# Android IME: is tehere a way to get or calc the cursor's absolute coordinates on screen

Tags: android, coordinates, ime, android-input-method, cursor-position

I'm creating a new [IME](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#InputMethodLifecycle) for android and I want to render a floating UI depending on the cursor's position. 
I've already found that if I override the [onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(android.view.inputmethod.CursorAnchorInfo) function of InputMethodService (Build version Lollipop or later) than I can get the coordinates of the cursor **in the edittext**, if I request the updates like: `inputConnection.requestCursorUpdates(InputConnection.CURSOR_UPDATE_MONITOR)`.

But how can I calc the **absolute** coordinates of the cursor (from the top left corner) in the IME?? Is there a HACK or any solution for this? Please help me! What is this `onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo` function for if I cannot use it for rendering a view next to the cursor :( ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the IME(keyboard) developer only. If you are App developer, you may want to try getSelectionStart() method of TextView or other input instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am an IME developer :(. Actually I found the part of the solution, so I will edit my question, thanks for the reminder. :)